# Why does Int32.TryParse reset the out parameter when not able to convert?

Tags: c#

if I run this C# code

```
int realInt = 3;  
string foo = "bar";  
Int32.TryParse(foo, out realInt); 

Console.WriteLine(realInt);  
Console.Read();
```

I get 0. And I would like to know why! Cause I cannot find any reason why it would. This forces me to make temp variables for every parsing. So please! Great coders of the universe, enlighten me!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is "out", not "ref". Inside the method it **has** to assign it (without reading it first) to satisfy the meaning of "out".

Actually, "out" is a *language* concern (not a framework one) - so a managed C++ implementation could probably ignore this... but it is more consistent to follow it.

In reality; if the method returns false you simply shouldn't look at the value; treat it as garbage until it is next assigned. It is stated to return 0, but that is rarely useful.

---

Also - if it didn't do this (i.e. if it preserved the value); what would this print:

```
int i;
int.TryParse("gibber", out i);
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

That is perfectly valid C#... so what does it print?

Comment: An explanation as to *why* it is like this, is so that you can assert that the variable will *always* have been set in any code after the `TryParse` call, even if the variable was not initialized earlier in the code (so the compiler doesn't throw an error when you use the variable after the `TryParse` call; try doing the same with a function that uses the `ref` keyword.)

Answer (score 7):

[The Int32.TryParse Method (String, Int32) doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) says:

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.
>
> result
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> When this method returns, contains the 32-bit signed integer value equivalent to the number contained in s, if the conversion succeeded, **or zero if the conversion failed**. The conversion fails if the s parameter is null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), is not of the correct format, or represents a number less than MinValue or greater than MaxValue. This parameter is passed uninitialized.

Answer (score 4):

Because the parameter is an out parameter you don't have to initialize **realInt** when you declare it, since the compiler can see that you're passing it to a method that is guaranteeded to set it to something (because of the "out").

Now, becuase it's an out parameter the TryParse is required to set it to something. It sets it to 0 becuase this is the default value for an int under most situations in C#.

You could write it as:

```
int realInt;
string foo="bar";
if(int.TryParse(foo,out realInt)==false)
{
  realInt=3;
}
```

Comment: Better way of writing it would be just to put a ! operator at the beginning of the TryParse i.e. if (!Int32.TryParse(foo, out realInt))

Answer (score 2):

Because this is how the 'out' contract works. Whenever you pass an `out` param to a function, its the responsibility of the function to initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

the MSDN documentation for [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(VS.80).aspx) states that if the conversion fails the result will always return 0.

You are usually supposed to either use a temporary result variable i.e.

```
int value;
bool succeeded = Int32.TryParse("astring", out value);
if (succeeded)
{
  // use value in some way
}
```

Or you just wrap the full method in an if statement

```
int value;
if (Int32.TryParse("astring", out value))
{
  // use value in some way
}
```

Personally I find the latter the better option.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class IntHelper
{
    public static bool TryParse(string s, ref int outValue)
    {
        int newValue;
        bool ret = int.TryParse(s, out newValue);
        if (ret) outValue = newValue;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because (at least in C#) the method that takes one or more out parameters must guarantee that they write back to them. That way you do not need to initialize local fields in a method before passing them as out arguments to a method.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's part of the C# spec:

> 10.5.1.3 Output parameters 
>   ...
>   Within a method, just like a local variable, an output parameter is initially considered > unassigned and must be definitely assigned before its value is used.
>
> Every output parameter of a method must be definitely assigned before the method returns.

If this is the case, you shouldn't rely on the resulting value.

Answer (score 0):

Since the second parameter to `TryParse` is an `out` parameter the `TryParse` method is forced to initialize the parameter. Had the parameter been `ref` instead of `out` you would get your desired behaviour. However, since the `TryParse` method only needs to ouput a number and not get any number as input `out` is the proper choice for the parameter.