# Why do TryParse methods uses an out parameter and not a ref

Tags: c#, parsing

Somewhat on the back of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1141931/373706) that asks about the behaviour of the `out` parameter but more focused as to why these `TryParse` methods use `out` and not `ref`.

There have been some scenarios where you do want to initialise a value to the argument before parsing and keep that when the parsing fails but do not really care if it does fail. However because of the `out` parameter the value is reset.

This scenario could look like this...

```
int arg = 123;
Int32.TryParse(someString, ref arg);
```

However because of the `out` parameter we have to write it like this, which is more verbose...

```
int arg;
if(!Int32.TryParse(someString, out arg)
{
    arg = 123;
}
```

I realise that knowing that the parsing failed can be very useful however the use of `ref` does not preclude this.

So why do these TryParse methods use `out` and not `ref`?

Comment: Also, why isn't there a `T TryParse(string value)` which just returns `default(T)` if the parse fails?

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: Because you wouldn't be able to distinguish between `"0"` and `"o"`.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: Because then you can't tell the difference between these two: "0" (parses to 0 successfully) and "apples" (parses unsuccessfully, defaults to 0).

Comment: @JohnFeminella: Where did you learn that obscure bit of information?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wouldn't say I "learned" it -- just seems like a straighforward conclusion of what happens if you took Bennor's approach.

Comment: Yeah I understand all that, but there are definitely times where you don't care and just want to default if the value doesn't parse.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: Then just use the value of the `out` parameter and ignore the return value of `TryParse`.

Comment: I know how to do it, and I've done it hundreds if not thousands of times. I just think the use of an out parameter is unnecessarily complicated. `int x = int.TryParse("not an int", out x) ? x : 0;` is about the shortest you can get it using the current implementation. `int x = int.TryParse("not an int") ?? 0;` is a lot clearer.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy TryParse sets the out parameter to zero if the parse is unsuccessful, so you can just do `int x; int.TryParse("not an int", out x);`

Comment: Yeah, but that's not always what you want. Take DateTime for example :)

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy I would suppose something like `DateTime x = DateTime.TryParse("not a date", DateTime.Now)` or (as an extension method to string as we can't change DateTime) `DateTime x = "not a date".ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)` with `DateTime.Now` being the default value. `public static DateTime ToDateTime(this string str, DateTime defaultValue) { DateTime val; if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out val)) return val; return defaultValue; }`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because the normal use pattern is exactly the opposite of what you're describing.

People should be able to write

```
int arg;
if (!Int32.TryParse(someString, ref arg)) {
    Waaah;
}
```

Had `TryParse` taken a `ref` parameter, this would require a useless initialization.

The real question is why there isn't an `int? int.TryParse(string)` method.

Comment: @SLaks... true, true considering it was added in .net2.0 which supported nullable types. As for useless initialisation valid point. Perhaps the framework can suppport int? ref and out overloads. ahhh

Comment: The last part of your answer is exactly what I was getting at. A nullable return value would solve the defaulting problem while still providing the same amount of information if required. It just feels really clunky having to declare a variable to use as an out parameter.

Comment: I think the answer is probably just that the existing pattern for TryParse predates generics, so Nullable<T> wasn't an option.

Comment: @BennorMcCarthy: I know.  However, they should have added it later (and still ought to)

Comment: Yeah, I definitely agree. Easy enough to implement ourselves, but it would be a lot cleaner if it was implemented for us.

Comment: Another alternative to `int? int.TryParse(string)` is `bool int.TryParse(string s, out num, int defaultValue)`

Answer (score 5):

You use `out` to indicate that the parameter is not being used, only set. The caller is **required** to assign a value before the method returns:

```
int n;
if (Int32.TryParse("47", out n)) { // Works fine; `n` will be set to the
  // ..                            // result of the parse.
}
```

If you used `ref`, you would have to initialize the value beforehand, which is silly since it's going to be overwritten anyway:

```
int n;
if (Int32.TryParse("47", ref n)) { // Kablammo! `n` isn't initialized.
  // ..
}
```

That's precisely the point of TryParse: you're guaranteed to have a value in the `out` parameter that represents the output of the parsing attempt. The return value of true or false indicates whether you should care about the result or ignore it.

Comment: Semantically TryXXX implies that it will try to do something... if it fails then the should the not be modified and knowing about the failure be enough. In this case I would expect a ref argument and explicitly init the arg to what I want. Although as @SLaks points out this would be unnecessary in most cases

Comment: "if it fails then the should the not be modified and knowing about the failure be enough" -- this is only true if most people wanted the result of the parse to default to something other than zero. If that was true, then `default(T)` for integers shouldn't be zero. But it is, so what you ask for is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

That's because an `out` parameter fits better to what the method does.

If it used a `ref` parameter, then you *have* to provide an input to the method. This would not work:

```
int arg;
if (Int32.TryParse(someString, ref arg)) { // error - variable is not initialsed
```

The method doesn't expect any input in the value parameter, if you would have to provide an input value, it's not obvious what that would be, or how that would be used.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience anyway, there are many more times when you do not want to bother with initialization, than when you want to provide a default value. Parse was designed with this in mind.

The question is a good one, and I don't think there is a serious problem using one approach or the other. The .NET team chose the out approach, since they couldn't use both without adding a separate method to int, which would be disgustingly redundant.